# Google Sheets API Sort column by date

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I want to, by using python googleapiclient.discovery, sort a google sheet by a column of dates. I assume there may be a way to do this via batchUpdate, given [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data#sort_a_range_with_multiple_sorting_specifications), but I can't quite figure out what the syntax would be here.

In gs, the sort I want to do looks like:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
  var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort(1)
}
```

I did see that there is a way using googleapiclient (.scripts()) to call a gs script like above but I want to avoid turning this into a Cloud Project. I am also aware that a script like above could be set on an on edit trigger but ideally I do not want to not trigger this on every change, only when another external job runs.

Answer (score 3):

Google Sheets API Sort column by date
[Google Sheets API Sort column by date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63674107/7108653)
https://stackoverflow.com/users/9004050/gustavmauler

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to convert the Google Apps Script in your question to the python script.
- At python script, you want to use googleapis for python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, the method of "spreadsheets.batchUpdate" of Sheets API is used.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set the Spreadsheet ID and sheet ID.

```
spreadsheet_id = '###'  # Please set the spreadsheet ID.
sheet_id = '###'  # Please set the sheet ID.

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
requests = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "sortRange": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                    "startRowIndex": 2,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0
                },
                "sortSpecs": [
                    {
                        "dataSourceColumnReference": {
                            "name": "A"
                        },
                        "sortOrder": "ASCENDING"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
res = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(body=requests, spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id).execute()
print(res)
```

- When above script is run, the same result of your Google Apps Script can be obtained.
- In this sample, `range` object means `sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn())`.

  - In the case of `getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn())`, for example, when the data range is "A1:B10", `getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn())` is "A3:B11". So I used above range.

#### Note:

- About the authorization script, please check the Quickstart. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)- This sample script supposes that you have already been able to use Sheets API.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [SortRangeRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#sortrangerequest)